# TypeScript and field initializers

Tags: typescript

How to init a new class in TS in such a way (example in C# to show what I want):

```
// ... some code before
return new MyClass { Field1 = "ASD", Field2 = "QWE" };
// ...  some code after
```

Comment: The "solution" you just appended to your question is not valid TypeScript or JavaScript. But it is valuable to point out that it is the most intuitive thing to try.

Comment: @JacobFoshee not valid JavaScript? See my Chrome Dev Tools: http://i.imgur.com/vpathu6.png *(but Visual Studio Code or any other TypeScript linted would inevitably complain)*

Comment: @MichalStefanow the OP edited the question after I posted that comment. He did have `return new MyClass { Field1: "ASD", Field2: "QWE" };`

Comment: Please don't put answers in questions - if you have an answer, write it below.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can I ask why you edited my answer back to Revision 1? It was corrected after years by me and looking at the popularity it was necessary to point the right solutions in one place... I don't understand how Rev1 is better than Rev7?

Comment: The first revision was a _question_. If you want to write answers, they go in the answers section. It seems like the author of the accepted answer would like you to choose a different one, which is a more appropriate way to highlight solutions than editing them into the question.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

### Update

Since writing this answer, better ways have come up. Please see the other answers below that have more votes and a better answer. I cannot remove this answer since it's marked as accepted.

---

### Old answer

There is an issue on the TypeScript codeplex that describes this: [Support for object initializers](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/334).

As stated, you can already do this by using interfaces in TypeScript instead of classes:

```
interface Name {
    givenName: string;
    surname: string;
}
class Person {
    name: Name;
    age: number;
}

var bob: Person = {
    name: {
        givenName: "Bob",
        surname: "Smith",
    },
    age: 35,
};
```

Comment: In your example, bob is not an instance of class Person. I don't see how this is equivalent to the C# example.

Comment: How is "Bob" not a "Person" instance? To me it clearly is declaring `bob` as a `Person` and providing the properties for the instance.

Comment: interface names are better to be started with capital "I"

Comment: 1. Person is not a class and 2. @JackWester is right, bob is not an instanceof Person. Try alert(bob instanceof Person);
In this code example Person is there for Type Assertion purposes only.

Comment: You can't use an interface if you're using properties though - you need to use a class which doesn't support inline initialization. It would still be a very handy feature to be able set values inline when an object is instantiated rather than `let myPerson: Person = new Person(); myPerson.name = 'hank'; myPerson.age = 4;`

Comment: I agree with Jack and Jaques, and I think its worth repeating. Your bob is of the *type* `Person`, but it is not at all an instance of `Person`. Imagine that `Person` actually would be a class with a complex constructor and a bunch of methods, this approach would fall flat on its face. It's good that a bunch of people found your approach useful, but it's not a solution to the question as it's stated and you could just as well use a class Person in your example instead of an interface, it would be the same type.

Answer (score 650):

**Updated 07/12/2016:**
[Typescript 2.1 introduces Mapped Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/12/07/announcing-typescript-2-1/) and provides `Partial<T>`, which allows you to do this....

```
class Person {
    public name: string = "default"
    public address: string = "default"
    public age: number = 0;

    public constructor(init?:Partial<Person>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}

let persons = [
    new Person(),
    new Person({}),
    new Person({name:"John"}),
    new Person({address:"Earth"}),    
    new Person({age:20, address:"Earth", name:"John"}),
];
```

**Original Answer:**

My approach is to define a separate `fields` variable that you pass to the constructor. The trick is to redefine all the class fields for this initialiser as optional. When the object is created (with its defaults) you simply assign the initialiser object onto `this`;

```
export class Person {
    public name: string = "default"
    public address: string = "default"
    public age: number = 0;

    public constructor(
        fields?: {
            name?: string,
            address?: string,
            age?: number
        }) {
        if (fields) Object.assign(this, fields);
    }
}
```

or do it manually (bit more safe):

```
if (fields) {
    this.name = fields.name || this.name;       
    this.address = fields.address || this.address;        
    this.age = fields.age || this.age;        
}
```

usage:

```
let persons = [
    new Person(),
    new Person({name:"Joe"}),
    new Person({
        name:"Joe",
        address:"planet Earth"
    }),
    new Person({
        age:5,               
        address:"planet Earth",
        name:"Joe"
    }),
    new Person(new Person({name:"Joe"})) //shallow clone
];
```

and console output:

```
Person { name: 'default', address: 'default', age: 0 }
Person { name: 'Joe', address: 'default', age: 0 }
Person { name: 'Joe', address: 'planet Earth', age: 0 }
Person { name: 'Joe', address: 'planet Earth', age: 5 }
Person { name: 'Joe', address: 'default', age: 0 }
```

This gives you basic safety and property initialization, but its all optional and can be out-of-order. You get the class's defaults left alone if you don't pass a field.

You can also mix it with required constructor parameters too -- stick `fields` on the end.

About as close to C# style as you're going to get I think ([actual field-init syntax was rejected](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3895)). I'd much prefer proper field initialiser, but doesn't look like it will happen yet.

For comparison, If you use the casting approach, your initialiser object must have ALL the fields for the type you are casting to, plus don't get any class specific functions (or derivations) created by the class itself.

Comment: +1. This actually creates an instance of a class (which most of these solutions don't), keeps all the functionality inside the constructor (no Object.create or other cruft outside), and explicitly states the property name instead of relying on param ordering (my personal preference here). 
It does lose type/compile safety between the params and properties, though.

Comment: @Fiddles yes, it does lose compile checks between the params & properties, but those are collocated in the same file, probably a few lines separating them. If you ever remove or change the type of a class property you will get a compile error if you map any `fields` property to it. I think method results in the least number of surprises.

Comment: Using Partial<T> makes every parameter optional, in my case some parameters are optional (fields already have a default value), and some parameters are required (they are not initialized with a default value at field declaration).
Is there any solution for this scenario? (Imagine a student class, that extends Person, with a required, non-initialized, field, new Student({ requiredField: 5 }), new Student({ }) //error)

Comment: @user1817787 you'd probably be better off defining anything that has a default as optional in the class itself, but assign a default. Then don't use `Partial<>`, just `Person` - that will require you to pass an object that has the required fields. that said, [see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) for ideas (See Pick) that limit Type Mapping to certain fields.

Comment: @user1817787 Just a thought: if you have a Large class and want them all to be optional in the ctor _except_ for a few (like an id number) then you could use union: i.e.  `constructor(init?: Partial<Person> & {age}) `.

Comment: This really should be the answer. Its the best solution to this issue.

Comment: that is GOLDEN piece of code `public constructor(init?:Partial<Person>) {         Object.assign(this, init); }`

Comment: if you have a hierarchy, lets say a `Person` has a list of orders `Order[]` then you can add `orders: Partial<Order>[]` to the constructor data structure, and after `Object.assign` add `this.orders = fields.orders.map(s => new Order(s));` where you do exactly the same thing in the constructor for `class Order`. Without the explicit mapping you won't get `Order` objects for the child data.

Comment: If Object.assign is showing an error like it was for me, please see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860354/2621693

Comment: I think in this case (for domain model) you should better use interface instead of class.  It s a best practice [encourage by angular](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) for example. Interfaces are use at compilation time for type checking and unlike classes, interfaces are completely removed during compilation.
So they will not add any unnecessary bloat to our final JavaScript code.

Comment: @rdhainaut while you'd be correct with regard to the example - the question is how to initialize a class.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to improve it a bit for my needs - I wanted all the fields to be mandatory and I wanted it to work with functions as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817647/126574

Comment: Is it possible to use this syntax for a derived class? What would the constructor look like? As is, I see "Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call."

Comment: @MeirionHughes in re @user1817787: If you omit the `Partial<>`, the approach won't work if your class contains any functions. Otherwise, TypeScript will give you TS2345.

Comment: Alright, I see that @VitalyB has solved exactly this problem below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817647/13994294

Comment: It doesn't work if you have non-null reference properties in the class. TSC doesn't recognize `Object.assign` as a property initializer, so you get this error: "Property 'x' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."

Answer (score 64):

Below is a solution that combines a shorter application of `Object.assign` to more closely model the original `C#` pattern.

But first, lets review the techniques offered so far, which include:

1. Copy constructors that accept an object and apply that to `Object.assign`
2. A clever `Partial<T>` trick within the copy constructor
3. Use of "casting" against a POJO
4. Leveraging `Object.create` instead of `Object.assign`

Of course, each have their pros/cons.  Modifying a target class to create a copy constructor may not always be an option.  And "casting" loses any functions associated with the target type.  `Object.create` seems less appealing since it requires a rather verbose property descriptor map.

## Shortest, General-Purpose Answer

So, here's yet another approach that is somewhat simpler, maintains the type definition and associated function prototypes, and more closely models the intended `C#` pattern:

```
const john = Object.assign( new Person(), {
    name: "John",
    age: 29,
    address: "Earth"
});
```

That's it.  The only addition over the `C#` pattern is `Object.assign` along with 2 parenthesis and a comma.  Check out the working example below to confirm it maintains the type's function prototypes.  No constructors required, and no clever tricks.

## Working Example

This example shows how to initialize an object using an approximation of a `C#` field initializer:

```js
class Person {
    name: string = '';
    address: string = '';
    age: number = 0;

    aboutMe() {
        return `Hi, I'm ${this.name}, aged ${this.age} and from ${this.address}`;
    }
}

// typescript field initializer (maintains "type" definition)
const john = Object.assign( new Person(), {
    name: "John",
    age: 29,
    address: "Earth"
});

// initialized object maintains aboutMe() function prototype
console.log( john.aboutMe() );
```

Comment: Like this one too, can create a user object from a javascript object

Comment: Object.assign is a really nice solution. Clean and to the point without altering the constructor signature.

Answer (score 35):

You can affect an anonymous object casted in your class type.
**Bonus**: In visual studio, you benefit of intellisense this way :)

```
var anInstance: AClass = <AClass> {
    Property1: "Value",
    Property2: "Value",
    PropertyBoolean: true,
    PropertyNumber: 1
};
```

Edit:

**WARNING** If the class has methods, the instance of your class will not get them.  If AClass has a constructor, it will not be executed.  If you use instanceof AClass, you will get false.

**In conclusion, you should used interface and not class**.
The most common use is for the domain model declared as Plain Old Objects.
Indeed, for domain model you should better use interface instead of class. Interfaces are use at compilation time for type checking and unlike classes, interfaces are completely removed during compilation.

```
interface IModel {
   Property1: string;
   Property2: string;
   PropertyBoolean: boolean;
   PropertyNumber: number;
}

var anObject: IModel = {
     Property1: "Value",
     Property2: "Value",
     PropertyBoolean: true,
     PropertyNumber: 1
 };
```

Comment: If `AClass` contained methods, `anInstance` wouldn't get them.

Comment: Also if AClass has a constructor, it will not be executed.

Comment: Also if you do `anInstance instanceof AClass` you'll get `false` at runtime.

Comment: This doesn't do what @Nikron is asking. This doesn't instantiate a class. It creates an object, and then tells TS that it is said class. It isn't any different than saying `({} as any as AClass)`

Answer (score 23):

I suggest an approach that does not require Typescript 2.1:

```
class Person {
    public name: string;
    public address?: string;
    public age: number;

    public constructor(init:Person) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }

    public someFunc() {
        // todo
    }
}

let person = new Person(<Person>{ age:20, name:"John" });
person.someFunc();
```

key points:

- Typescript 2.1 not required, `Partial<T>` not required
- **It supports functions** (in comparison with simple type assertion which does not support functions)

Comment: It doesn't respect mandatory fields: `new Person(<Person>{});` (because casting) and to be clear too; using Partial<T> supports functions. Ultimately, if you have required fields (plus prototype functions) you'll need to do: `init: { name: string, address?: string, age: number }` and drop the cast.

Comment: Also [when we get conditional type mapping](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424) you'll be able to map just the functions to partials, and keep the properties as is. :)

Comment: Instead of the sophisticated `class` then `var`, if I do `var dog: {name: string} = {name: 'will be assigned later'};`, it compiles and works. Any deficiency or issue? Oh, `dog` has very small scope and specific, meaning only one instance.

Answer (score 15):

In some scenarios it may be acceptable to use **[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)**. The Mozilla reference includes a polyfill if you need back-compatibility or want to roll your own initializer function.

Applied to your example:

```
Object.create(Person.prototype, {
    'Field1': { value: 'ASD' },
    'Field2': { value: 'QWE' }
});
```

#### Useful Scenarios

- Unit Tests
- Inline declaration

In my case I found this useful in unit tests for two reasons:

1. When testing expectations I often want to create a slim object as an expectation
2. Unit test frameworks (like Jasmine) may compare the object prototype (`__proto__`) and fail the test. For example:

```js
var actual = new MyClass();
actual.field1 = "ASD";
expect({ field1: "ASD" }).toEqual(actual); // fails
```

The output of the unit test failure will not yield a clue about what is mismatched.

3. In unit tests I can be selective about what browsers I support

Finally, the solution proposed at http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/334 does not support inline json-style declaration.  For example, the following does not compile:

```
var o = { 
  m: MyClass: { Field1:"ASD" }
};
```

Answer (score 15):

I wanted a solution that would have the following:

- All the data objects are required and must be filled by the constructor.
- No need to provide defaults.
- Can use functions inside the class.

Here is the way that I do it:

```
export class Person {
  id!: number;
  firstName!: string;
  lastName!: string;

  getFullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  constructor(data: OnlyData<Person>) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}

const person = new Person({ id: 5, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" });
person.getFullName();
```

All the properties in the constructor are mandatory and may not be omitted without a compiler error.

It is dependant on the `OnlyData` that filters out `getFullName()` out of the required properties and it is defined like so:

```
// based on : https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c
type FilterFlags<Base, Condition> = { [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? never : Key };
type AllowedNames<Base, Condition> = FilterFlags<Base, Condition>[keyof Base];
type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, AllowedNames<Base, Condition>>;
type OnlyData<T> = SubType<T, (_: any) => any>;
```

Current limitations of this way:

- Requires TypeScript 2.8
- Classes with getters/setters

Comment: This answer seems closest to ideal to me. Wondering if we can do any better with typescript 3+

Comment: As far as I can tell this is the best way forward as of today. Thank you.

Comment: There is one problem with this solution, @VitalyB: As soon as the methods have parameters, this breaks: While getFullName() { return "bar" } works, getFullName(str: string):string { return str } does not work

Comment: @floriannorbertbepunkt What exactly is not working for you? It seems to be working fine for me...

Comment: This works for most cases! It's problematic if one of the class fields is a function type, as it will be ignored as well.

Comment: @VolodymyrBobyr That's true. I use TypeScript's Omit functions to manually exclude such items. Usually, this isn't a problem, however, since most of the classes I define this way have no functions.

Comment: @VitalyB check out my answer below -- it supports functions https://stackoverflow.com/a/65875146/12658818

Comment: @VolodymyrBobyr I like it! Will be using your solution instead

Answer (score 14):

I'd be more inclined to do it this way, using (optionally) automatic properties and defaults. You haven't suggested that the two fields are part of a data structure, so that's why I chose this way.

You could have the properties on the class and then assign them the usual way. And obviously they may or may not be required, so that's something else too. It's just that this is such nice syntactic sugar.

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(public Field1:string = "", public Field2:string = "")
    {
        // other constructor stuff
    }
}

var myClass = new MyClass("ASD", "QWE");
alert(myClass.Field1); // voila! statement completion on these properties
```

Comment: My deepest apologies. But you didn't actually "ask about field initializers", so it's natural to assume that you might be interested in alternative ways of newing up a class in TS. You might give a tiny bit more information in your question if you are so ready to downvote.

Comment: +1 constructor is the way to go where possible; but in cases where you have a lot of fields and want to only initialise some of them, I think my answer makes things easier.

Comment: If you have many fields, initializing an object like this would be pretty unwieldy as you would be passing the constructor a wall of nameless values. That isn't to say this method has no merit; it would be best used for simple objects with few fields. Most publications say that around four or five parameters in a member's signature is the upper limit.

Just pointing this out because I found a link to this solution on someone's blog while searching for TS initializers. I have objects with 20+ fields that need to be initialized for unit tests.

Comment: This is called "Parameter Properties": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties

Answer (score 13):

You could have a class with optional fields (marked with ?) and a constructor that receives an instance of the same class.

```
class Person {
    name: string;     // required
    address?: string; // optional
    age?: number;     // optional

    constructor(person: Person) {
        Object.assign(this, person);
    }
}

let persons = [
    new Person({ name: "John" }),
    new Person({ address: "Earth" }),    
    new Person({ age: 20, address: "Earth", name: "John" }),
];
```

In this case, you will not be able to omit the required fields. This gives you fine-grained control over the object construction.

You could use the constructor with the Partial type as noted in other answers:

```
public constructor(init?:Partial<Person>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
}
```

The problem is that all fields become optional and it is not desirable in most cases.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that if Person class has methods, the constructor's argument will also be expected to have methods.

Answer (score 5):

To init a class without redeclaring all the properties for defaults:

```
class MyClass{ 
  prop1!: string  //required to be passed in
  prop2!: string  //required to be passed in
  prop3 = 'some default'
  prop4 = 123

  constructor(opts:{prop1:string, prop2:string} & Partial<MyClass>){
    Object.assign(this,opts)
  }
}
```

This combines some of the already excellent answers

Comment: how do I call this constructor?
const opts: {   prop1: 'helloworld'  }

new MyClass(opts ???);

Comment: @DanielMethner created by calling

MyClass({ prop1:"foo", props2:"bar" })

Answer (score 4):

This is another solution:

```js
return {
  Field1 : "ASD",
  Field2 : "QWE" 
} as myClass;
```

Comment: Can we ensure the constructor of the class has executed if we do it this way?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best solution I've found for this.

Declare a function that can be used as a decorator. I'm calling it **AutoReflect**

```
export function AutoReflect<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  return class extends constructor {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(args)
      if (typeof args[0] === 'object') {
        Object.assign(this, args[0]);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

What this does is expects an object in the constructor and assigns the members to the the class instance.
Use this on a class declaration

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

@AutoReflect
class Person implements IPerson {
  name: string;
  number: number;
  constructor(model?: Partial<IPerson>){}
}
```

In the constructor of your model, you can make the model optional, and in using the Partial you can new up an instance without setting all the property values

```
new Person({
   name: 'Santa'
});
```

This method creates a new instance of the class you want and also has a C# object initialization feeling to it.

Comment: seems to not working anymore

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that:

- doesn't force you to make all fields optional (unlike `Partial<...>`)
- differentiates between class methods and fields of function type (unlike the `OnlyData<...>` solution)
- provides a nice structure by defining a Params interface
- doesn't need to repeat variable names & types more than once

The only drawback is that it *looks* more complicated at first.

```js
// Define all fields here
interface PersonParams {
  id: string
  name?: string
  coolCallback: () => string
}

// extend the params interface with an interface that has
// the same class name as the target class
// (if you omit the Params interface, you will have to redeclare
// all variables in the Person class)
interface Person extends PersonParams { }

// merge the Person interface with Person class (no need to repeat params)
// person will have all fields of PersonParams
// (yes, this is valid TS)
class Person {
  constructor(params: PersonParams) {
    // could also do Object.assign(this, params);

    this.id = params.id;
    this.name = params.name;

    // intellisence will expect params
    // to have `coolCallback` but not `sayHello`
    this.coolCallback = params.coolCallback;
  }

  // compatible with functions
  sayHello() {
    console.log(`Hi ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

// you can only export on another line (not `export default class...`)
export default Person;
```

Comment: I like your version best :) I've been using it since

Comment: This version is the reason why I'm here in the first place. I mean it's great for small code bases but this becomes a lot of boilerplate over time and becomes unwieldy for large objects.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with type casting.

```
return <MyClass>{ Field1: "ASD", Field2: "QWE" };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, (1) this is not type-casting, but a compile-time type-_assertion_, (2) the question asked *"how to init a new **class**"* (emphasis mine), and this approach will fail to accomplish that. It would be certainly nice if TypeScript had this feature, but unfortunately, that's not the case.

Comment: where is the definition of `MyClass`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an old version of typescript < 2.1 then you can use similar to the following which is basically casting of any to typed object:

```
const typedProduct = <Product>{
                    code: <string>product.sku
                };
```

> NOTE: Using this method is only good for data models as it will remove
>   all the methods in the object. It's basically casting any object to a
>   typed object

Answer (score 0):

```js
type ExcludeMethods<T> = Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T]>;

class MyClass {
  public name!: string;
  public age!: number;
  public optional?: boolean;
  private yep: string = "";

  constructor(props: ExcludeMethods<typeof MyClass.prototype>) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }

  public method() {
  }
}

const thing = new MyClass({
  name: "bob",
  age: 15
});
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmECyFgAsD2aAzgDwAqAfFALxQAKAlggNbkA0UA3lANoDSUBgDsozCCHwAzKGQC6ALhn9ZUCHGAQhxKADEUQhMAb4RAfihCIANwgAnKIoEBfHmInS5FANwAoH8gBDIiIoTBAAYSQgkM4fKCgwFAAjJCYLAIBbCABCRSJgW2EAc194xJS0gKKcxSEUDKS7UoTk1IQofDAjEwCkU0Uk-HwkCAChZrBCqwCNKBAIMDyC4pooACI13zioBBN82xRDfFsACknOokV4ZHQsHAJiElBIKVCIqOCAOnPgfGeICgASi423iAHkkgArCCGT7RBhFIQnPAMIgcc5gIiA5pOPxlVppLJ4QgnYGxeK43H%20PbAKAooRFVaWADub0i0RO5PSWUUa0GSTWbG2VQgigAjABWHxObFAA)

Answer (score 0):

how's this...

```typescript
function as_<T>(o: T) { return o; };
```

```typescript
// ... some code before
return as_<MyClass>({ Field1 = "ASD", Field2 = "QWE" });
// ...  some code after
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type ExcludeMethods<T> = Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T]>;

class Person{
  name: string = "N/A";
  age: number = 0;
  gender?: "male" | "female"

  constructor(init?:ExcludeMethods<Person>){
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }

  Describe(){return `${this.name} ${this.age} ${this.gender ?? ""}` }
}

var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person({
  name: "John",
  age: 20
});
var p3 = new Person({
  name: "Mary",
  age: 25,
  gender: "female"
});

console.log(p1.Describe()) // N/A 0
console.log(p2.Describe()) // John 20
console.log(p3.Describe()) // Mary 25 female
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is the rev7 of OP. Here is that revision
.=======================================================

When I was writing this question I was pure .NET developer without much of JS knowledge. Also TypeScript was something completely new, announced as new C#-based superset of JavaScript. Today I see how stupid this question was.

Anyway if anyone still is looking for an answer, please, look at the possible solutions below.

First thing to note is in TS we shouldn't create empty classes for models. Better way is to create interface or type (depending on needs). Good article from Todd Motto: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
type MyType = { prop1: string, prop2: string };

return <MyType> { prop1: '', prop2: '' };
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

```
type MyType = { prop1: string, prop2: string };

return { prop1: '', prop2: '' } as MyType;
```

**SOLUTION 3 (when you really need a class):**

```
class MyClass {
   constructor(public data: { prop1: string, prop2: string }) {}
}
// ...
return new MyClass({ prop1: '', prop2: '' });
```

or

```
class MyClass {
   constructor(public prop1: string, public prop2: string) {}
}
// ...
return new MyClass('', '');
```

Of course in both cases you may not need casting types manually because they will be resolved from function/method return type.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to create new instance without set initial value when instance

1- you have to use class not interface

2- you have to set initial value when create class

```
export class IStudentDTO {
 Id:        number = 0;
 Name:      string = '';


student: IStudentDTO = new IStudentDTO();
```

Answer (score -2):

For more modern versions of TypeScript

Class definition

```
    export class PaymentRequestDto {
      public PaymentSource: number;
      public PaymentCenterUid: string;
      public ConnectedUserUid: string;
    }
```

And you have some values from somewhere:

```
    const PaymentCenter= 'EA0AC01E-D34E-493B-92FF-EB2D66512345';
    const PaymentSource= 4;
    const ConnectedUser= '2AB0D13C-2BBE-46F5-990D-533067BE2EB3';
```

Then you can initialize your object while being strongly typed.

```
    const parameters: PaymentRequestDto = {
        PaymentSource,
        PaymentCenterUid: PaymentCenter,
        ConnectedUserUid: ConnectedUser,
    };
```

PaymentSource doesn't require a name field specifier because the variable used has the same name as the field.

And this works with arrays too.

```
    const parameters: PaymentRequestDto [] = [
      {
        PaymentSource,
        PaymentCenterUid: PaymentCenter,
        ConnectedUserUid: ConnectedUser,
      },
      {
      . . . .
      }
    ];
```

Comment: This is not strongly typed. The parameters you've created are not typed correctly, they are effectively interfaces.