# Using TypeScript, and Object.assign gives me an error "property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing my question again because earlier it made little sense and I wasn't very clear.

I am receiving data from API that looks something like this:

```
{"photos":[{"id":1,"title":"photo_1_title"}]}
```

So, in my code, I have a `photos` variable, and a method called `getPhotos()`

I am using infinite scroll so when I reach the bottom of the page, I call `getPhotos()` again.

```
photos: any;

getPhotos() {
  this.photoService.getPhotos()
    .subscribe(
      photos => this.photos = photos
      // here, instead of doing this, I want to add the array of photos I get back to this.photos using Object.assign however it is giving me the said error
    )
}
```

So if the next time I call it, I get back `{"photos":[{"id":2,"title":"photo_2_title"}]}`, then I am trying to set `this.photos` to be

```
{"photos":[{"id":1,"title":"photo_1_title"}, {"id":2,"title":"photo_2_title"}]}
```

can someone help me with why
jsfiddle.net/ca46hLw9 doesn't work?  I thought assign is supposed to merge  contents of an object together right?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`Object.assign` is an ECMAScript2015 feature and does not exist in ECMAScript5 and lower.

You're most likely targeting to compile your Typescript for ECMAScript5 and therefor the Object interface does not have `assign` defined.

You can either target ECMAScript2015 by changing your TS compiler configuration with

`target: 'es6'`

or you can extend the ObjectConstructor interface with the method `assign`

```
declare interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign(...objects: Object[]): Object;
}
```

(you can add this declaration anywhere, redeclaring an interface extends it instead of overwriting it)

Or you can coerce `Object` to `any` and ignore its typing:

`(<any>Object).assign( this.photos, photos )`

Whichever you choose, keep in mind that if you want this to run on older browsers you need to add a polyfill. Most modern browsers are fairly close to implementing the ES2015 feature set, but they're not 100% there, meaning that some parts of your code will still fail if you rely on ES2015 functionality.

Typescript will not polyfill `Object.assign` when targetting ES5 or older, that is why you are getting this error. On the other hand, Babel does have polyfills in the form of plugins, which would mean you need to incorporate Babel transpilation into your build pipeline, see: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-assign/

As a final option you can consider using a library as Lodash or jQuery, which have their own implementation of `Object.assign` (called `extend`)

Comment: would the extending objectconstructor act as a polyfill?

Comment: Hi I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.  I tested with simple object, { a: 1 }, and tried to do `const test = Object.assign({ a: 1}, {b: 2});` but when I `console.log(test);` I see only `{b: 2}`

Comment: @user1354934 This is because you are trying to do a deep clone (objects inside of objects). Object.assign apparantly only does shallow clones. See the 2nd example on the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Bit late, but I think Angular 2 does polyfill Object.Assign - at least if you use Angular CLI.  There is a src/polyfills.ts file, that includes a reference to core-js/es6/object, which in turn seems to include the Object.Assign polyfill.

Answer (score 73):

With [Typescript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) or higher, you can use Object spread syntax instead.

```
let obj = { x: 1, y: "string" };
var newObj = {...obj, z: 3, y: 4}; // { x: number, y: number, z: number }
```

> The order of specifying spread operations determines what properties
>   end up in the resulting object; properties in later spreads “win out”
>   over previously created properties.

Comment: E.g: `const opts = { ...defaults, ...options }`

Comment: It's different when `obj` is created from a `new` expression.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work when "obj" is a constant. Otherwise it is a good solution.

Comment: Yeah, it does work for constant objects as well, since `Object.assign` accepts the target object as first parameter: `const constObj = {}; Object.assign(constObj, { ...defaults, ...options });`

Answer (score 1):

For typescript version 2.0 or higher, just modify the tsconfig.json file so the "lib" section includes "es6":

```
"lib": [
  "es5",
  "es6",
  "dom",
  "es2015.collection"
]
```