# TypeScript - Issue with Get property in object initializer

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using TypeScript with Angular2, following is my class declaration -

```
export /**
 * Stress
 */
class Student {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;

    constructor() {
    }

    get FullName() : string {
        return this.FirstName + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

When I try to initialize the above class using following code -

```
var stud1: Student = { FirstName:"John", LastName:"Troy" }
```

I am getting the following error -

```
Type '{ FirstName: string; LastName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Student'.
Property 'FullName' is missing in type '{ FirstName: string; LastName: string; }'.
```

Any help please what I am doing wrong here, or it is not supported yet by TypeScript?

Comment: *When I try to initialize the above class* I guess you mean "instantiate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct an object from your Student class you need to use the class' constructor.

```
var stud1 = new Student();
stud1.FirstName = "John";
stud1.LastName = "Troy";

console.log(stud1.FullName);
```

Or even better, let the constructor initialize object's fields:

```
class Student {
    FirstName: string; //this is public, unless you specify private
    LastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string){
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    //your FullName getter comes here
}

var stud1 = new Student("John", "Troy");
console.log(stud1.FullName);
```

Comment: I could have done that just that I find object initializers more handy. More so when I don't want to put every "set" property in constructor, which in this case I have to.
Thanks for the response.

Comment: To work with object initializer, Student will need to be Interface, but then Student will not be able to contain methods including getters.
They've discussed some options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142071/typescript-and-field-initializers).

Comment: Thanks Granga, that helps.