# Typescript default properties when type casting

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to typecast an object to a class type so that default property values are respected?

For instance:

```
class Person {
    name: string = "bob";
    age: number;
    sex: string;
}

var data = {
    "age": 23,
    "sex": "male"
}

var p = <Person>data;

console.log(p.name); // -> undefined
```

What is the simplest way to do it so `p.name` is bob?

***Edit**

This seems to work:

```
var record : Person = Object.assign(new Person(), p);
```

Is this good or bad practice?

Comment: you should clarify your question. Do you want an instance of class or enforce the type when casting an object? for example `var p:Person = {name="default", ... data}` will work and enforce the type, but it isn't an instance of the class. For that you'd probably be better off with a class constructor that takes an initializer. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142071/typescript-and-field-initializers/37682352#37682352

Comment: I want instance of class populated with data from the json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way that gives you an instance of the class is to use a constructor initialiser and make the fields with defaults optional:

```
class Person {
  name?: string = "bob";
  age: number;
  sex: string;
  constructor(opt: Person) {
    Object.assign(this, opt);
  }
}
```

or be explicit in what is and is not optional for initialization.

```
class Person {
  name: string = "bob";
  age: number;
  sex: string;
  constructor(opt: { name?: string, age: number; sex: string; }) {
    Object.assign(this, opt);
  }
}
```

or, if you don't care what is given just make the initializer fields all optional:

```
class Person {
  name: string = "bob";
  age: number;
  sex: string;
  constructor(opt?: Partial<Person>) {
    Object.assign(this, opt);
  }
}
```

if you don't care about it being an instance of the class, but you want to enforce the fields and types then **avoid casting** and set the type of the variable explicitly instead:

```
var data = {
    "age": 23,
    "sex": "male"
}

var p1:Person = {name:"bob", ... data}; // or
var p2:Person = {new Person(), ... data};
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why must default fields be optional?

Comment: it means you don't have to pass them through in the initialiser: eg: `new Person({age:20, sex:"male"})`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do so with [Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (type casting); they're evaluated at compile time, whereas [Default Values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#default-values) are resolved at runtime.

They are completely disparate phases.

Comment: What would be the way to go about doing it?  Any way to instantiate the object then merge properties after so default values are there?

Comment: yes, you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) them along with your *instance*: `{...p, ...overrides}`. or, if you want defaults: `{...defaults, ...p}`. you're gonna have to use `new` at some point either way.

Comment: I read that page on spread.  I couldn't see any apparent way it could be applied to merge objects.  I got it working with `Object.assign(new Person(), p)` though, not sure if thats a good practice to initiate all objects with default properties like that.

Comment: @Guerrilla - sounds awesome. if it suits your needs, you should post it as an answer.