# Shorthand for field initializer when class has computed property

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have a very simple class with a calculated property:

```
class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  get fuillName(): string {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

Now I want to create an object of type `Person`:

```
let p: Person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};
```

This gives me an error:

> Type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Person'. Property 'fuillName' is missing in type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }'.

Huh? `fullName` is a read-only property. So I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142071/typescript-and-field-initializers) and implemented a partial initializer:

```
constructor(init?: Partial<Person>) {
  Object.assign(this, init);
}
```

Same error. I know I can do this:

```
let p = new Person();
p.firstName = 'John';
p.lastName = 'Smith';
console.debug(p.fullName);
```

But is there a shorthand to initialize the class using the JSON syntax?

Comment: "Same error." -- Did you actually update your initialiser to call a constructor, like the answer you got it from shows?

Comment: Okay, the fact that you accepted @Vega's answer shows you indeed didn't do what the answer you were reading already showed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define Person class as follows:

```
  class Person {
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
      Object.assign(this, values);
    }

    get fullName(): string {
       return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  }
```

you can initialise a new user as the following:

```
  let p = new Person({firstName : 'John', lastName: 'Smith'}); //one line, two assignations
  console.log(p.fullName);
```

To go further:

```
  class Person {
     ....// as above
     set fullName(fullName: string){
         let splitName = fullName.split(" ");
         this.firstName = splitName[0] || '';
         this.lastName = splitName[1] || '';
     }
   }

   let p = new Person()
   p.fullName = "Paul Doe";
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DVYEz3Xv2hu9Vog4XDQH?p=preview)

Comment: This changes `fullName` to a function but it's an OK compromise I guess

Comment: Any reason you changed the OP's `Partial<Person>` to `Object`? That seems like it only introduces the possibility of doing things wrong, it means you don't get any hints when you e.g. accidentally type `fristName` instead of `firstName`.

Comment: @hvd, thank you! I omitted, mostly, because I thought that it wasn't relevant to the question. I should have probably used the safe navigation operator or  the class properties (which I think I did before editing..). I will update my answer taking in consideration your advice.