# Can Angular `HttpClient` `.get()` generics have non-simple property types? (e.g. other than `string` or `number`)

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, httpclient

I've burned a day researching the subject, and I haven't found any clues.  All I have found is *omission*, in that nothing I've read states that you *can* use non-simple types (by which I mean `string` and `number`) for the generic interface ("shape") when calling an Angular 4.4 `HttpClient.<T>get()`.

Rather than fail to describe the problem, the following example code is what I'm trying to do:

```
// Injected in my real code ... but these are the libs being used.
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

interface IMyDataItem {
    // In this example, using @Types/Decimal.js
    // It appears the "problem" exists for any types beside the simples (number/string etc)
    results: decimal.Decimal[];
}

class Service {
   doSomethingCool() {
       this._http
          .get<IMyDataItem>("url://somewhere")
          .subscribe(
             data => {
                // Call a method on the Decimal typed property
                data.results[0].pow(3, 3);
             }
          );
   }
}
```

Syntactically it compiles.  TypeScript correctly resolves the generic magic - and recognises that `data.results` is an array of type `Decimal`.

However in run-time (in Chrome, after transpiling to Javascript) the call to `pow()` fails, citing that the method does not exist (and indeed, debugging it shows that it is a plain old Javascript object).

I'm very new to TypeScript and Angular 4 - but this feels logical to me.  I've only asked the generic `get()` call to process the request as an interface.  It's had to determine how to construct an object that fulfills that interface.  Nowhere have I constructed a solid object which implements that interface, and nowhere have I constructed a `Decimal`.

(Update: This article further leads me to believe my gut... https://jameshenry.blog/typescript-classes-vs-interfaces/)

The [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) (and indeed every non-official source I've observed) demonstrates it working with (in my terms) "simple" types (specifically `number` and `string`) - which my gut says "makes sense" because a `JSON` object can have simple strings and simple numbers.

Am I missing the obvious?  Or is it just impossible to directly map to more complex class types?

If it is impossible - how do you normally go about handling it?  I've looked for "best practice" patterns - and come up short.

Again, my gut (and it is only *my gut* says I should have a private method inside a class which deals with API requests - and returns an `Observable` (to which the caller will subscribe) which gives a complex object type (e.g. an array of `User` classes, which have user-related methods on them):

```
class Service {
   // Return a complex object type Observable for consumption elsewhere
   doSomethingCool(): Observable<IMyDataItem> {
       return this._http
          .get<IMyDataItem>("url://somewhere");
   }
}
```

Does that make sense?  TIA.

Comment: I'm using `Angular 4.4` with the `HttpClientModule` - I've updated the question with it too.  Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm too tired for the day to read this article - but it does suggest (with a demonstration of using `Date` types) that it's possible. 
 https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - after an evening and half-day of frustration - I've concluded there isn't a "super clean" way of handling this.

An article on [Auth0.com](https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-3/) looked hopeful, creating a `Event` class (not just an interface) with several classed properties (`Date`) - but again just behaved on the basis that the types aren't real during run-time (they just satisfy the compiler).

As a not-super-clean way of working around this, I've utilised [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142071/typescript-and-field-initializers/37682352#37682352) which describes a fairly clean method of creating a constructor which accepts a partial to pre-fill properties.

In my classes where properties are anything other than simple numbers/strings etc, I'm constructing those properties in my class' constructor thusly:

```
export class Product {
    public name: string;
    public description: string;
    public viewPublic: boolean;
    public validFrom?: Date;
    public validTo?: Date;
    public _id?: string;

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142071/typescript-and-field-initializers/37682352#37682352
    /**
     * Constructor to help solidification of this model when a HttpClient.<T>Get() call is made.
     */
    public constructor(init?: Partial<Product>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);

        if (init.validFrom !== null && init.validFrom instanceof Date === false) {
            this.validFrom = new Date(this.validFrom.toString());
        }

        if (init.validTo !== null && init.validTo instanceof Date === false) {
            this.validTo = new Date(this.validTo.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

(So you can construct a `Product` class like `new Product({ name: "A product", validFrom: "2015-01-02T12:23:42"; })` and you are given a real `Product`object with real `Date` typed properties - rather than just strings.

This is a level of maintenance overhead which I didn't want, but feels acceptable in my gut.

Calling the `HttpClient` and having it return `Observable<Product>` in a more "solid way" (like I originally wanted) then becomes somewhat simpler:

```
   return this._http
        .get<Product[]>(this.productApiUrl)
        .map(res => new Product(res));
```

I'm using a `map()` to solidify the object to a real `Product`.

Finally to handle arrays, I added a helper method on the my API service:

```
/**
 * Solidifies an array of models when the source is JSON via HttpClient.<T>Get() etc
 */
private solidfyAll<T>(objs: T[], type: { new (partial: Partial<T>): T; }): T[] {
    let solidified = [];
    for (let obj of objs) {
        solidified.push(new type(obj));
    }
    return solidified;
}
```

Similarly this can be called on a `map` dealing with `Observable<Product[]>`:

```
    return this._http
        // type hint/strict the response structure against an interface
        .get<Product[]>(this.productApiUrl)
        .map(res => this.solidfyAll<Product>(res, Product));
```

You can see from the screenshot below, the `subscriber` now receives a true `Date` typed property as originally desired:

[image: Screenshot of truly classed object in observable subscriber]

Answer (score 0):

`http.get()` of Angular returns a `Response`. Try mapping it to JSON first:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

....
class Service {
    doSomethingCool(): Observable<IMyDataItem> {
        return this._http
            .get("url://somewhere");
            .map((response:Response) => response.json() as IMyDataItem);
    }
}
```

**p.s. You need to import `rxjs` to use `map()`**

**EDIT**

After the discussion on the comments, then my answer about this "Can Angular `HttpClient` `.get()` generics have non-simple property types" question is:

No, because by default `get()` method returns JSON by default. And based on [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp), JSON data type can only be a string, a number, an object (JSON object), an array, a boolean, or null.

Comment: I believe (I may be wrong) that this uses the older http library from Angular <=4.2.  I'm using the `HttpClient` library from Angular >=4.3 (see for example https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-intro/).  I am willing to consider moving back to the older library if that's "best".

Comment: @wally whoops thanks for the link, turns out this version 4 returns `json` by default.. yeah you are right, my bad then

Comment: @wally then have you tried instead of using `data.results[0].pow(3, 3);`, use something like `Math.pow(data.results[0], 3);` ? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Comment: :-) Yes I have.  And that works.  And I'd expect it to work.  I'm not caught up on the power function specifically - that's just an example.  What I'm stuck on is whether there's short-cut method to having the JSON mapped into real classes (like `Decimal`, or it could be `SomeOtherClassByMe`), in order that I can write neat methods against them.

Comment: @wally ah I see.. In that case I had once use an interface which has another interface as its property, something like `interface IProject { manager: IUser }`. But that is interface though, not a class. I believe if it is class, you need to initialize the class using the returned JSON as its constructor parameter? and then assign the JSON to the class properties  from the constructor? something like `let item = new Item(data.results[0]);`

Comment: @wally, based on this site https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp , JSON can only be a string, a number, an object (JSON object), an array, a boolean, or null

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm feeling - that possibly it's because ultimately all it's doing is blindly mapping those fixed set of types to an object which "implements" (at compile time - and in faith during run time!) properties of those types.  You're increasing my confidence that I'm not simply barking up the wrong tree!

Comment: @wally Let's see if other people have a better explanation about this. It is a great discussion btw, thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work without the need to define the model. It's annoying having to define and maintain them in multiple places (is there a solution?).

```
    this.http
      .get<Observable<any>>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.data = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
```

Can now be used just fine in a template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Full component code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

export class ProductListComponent {
  data: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getdata() {
    this.http
      .get<Observable<any>>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.data = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Versions

```
"rxjs": "6.6.7",
"@angular/core": "12.0.3",
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the JSON gets mapped to an object that has the properties of the specified type, but that does not have it's prototype, and therefore does not have the methods defined.

You can remedy this by doing `Object.assign(new MyObject(), data);`

I don't think that you will be able to use an interface, you'll have to use a class (a concrete implementation).