# Variable set in Constructor not visible

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display a simple list of Players. Now I get from my backend Server a List of Players. Now there can come back **Players** or **SpecialPlayers**(who inherit from Player).

And now I want to display in the list "*Player*" when its a **Player** and "*SpecialPlayer*" when its a **Special Player**, and I thougth I could achieve it with that code:

```
export class Player {
    name: string;
    mode: string;
    constructor() {
        this.mode="Player";
    }
}

export class SpecialPlayer extends Player{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.mode="SpecialPlayer"; 
    }
}
```

And thats my list:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr *ngFor="let player of players">
        <div>{{player.name}}</div>
        <div>{{player.mode}}</div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So the Name gets displayed, but the Mode not(or its gets displayed but has no content)...

The call to my backend server:

```
loadPlayers(): void {
    this.auth.loadPlayers().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.players= data;
      });
  }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So SpecialPlayer is subclass of Player? did SpecialPlayer extends Player yet?

Comment: Yes I just forgot to put it here ;)

Comment: And where does `players`, used in ngFor comes from? Is it through HttpClient?

Comment: From my Backend Server, I just added the call EDIT: Yes http Client

Comment: Your code is a component?

Comment: Yes this method is in a component

Comment: And how do you import those class ?

Comment: I do not think that that is the Problem, because the list is visible and the Players have the correct names, or what do you mean exactly? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that using http client your object is not really your class, it's simply a json object supporting only native types.

you are responsible to build it on client from what you receive from the server.

UPDATE -- 
You have to manually map the result. simplest way I know of is using a constructor with partial parameter.

see [Can Angular `HttpClient` `.get()` generics have non-simple property types? (e.g. other than `string` or `number`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569064/can-angular-httpclient-get-generics-have-non-simple-property-types-e-g#answer-46585109)

Comment: Ah Okay, and is there another way then to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You need extend SpecialPlayer class from Player

```
class SpecialPlayer extends Player
```