# instantiate typescript class instance with values (object initialization)

Tags: typescript

So in c# you can instantiate a class with values using the [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) syntax. In TypeScript there doesn't appear to be the same kind of object initializer syntax. What I've found is that you can initialize values using the following two methods:

**Constructor Initialization:**

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(num: number, str: string) {
    this.numProperty = num;
    this.strProperty = str;
  }
  numProperty: number;
  strProperty: string;
}

let myClassInstance = new MyClass(100, 'hello');
```

**Object Type Casting:**

```
class MyClass {
  numProperty: number;
  strProperty: string;
}

let myClassInstance = <MyClass>{
  numProperty: 100,
  strProperty: 'hello'
};
```

While I like using Object Type Casting syntax in TypeScript, it only works with simple DTO classes that don't have methods you need to use. This is because casting doesn't actually create an object of the class type you are casting to.

**Are there any other ways to do object initialization in TypeScript?**

Comment: related : [TypeScript and field initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142071/typescript-and-field-initializers)

Comment: Be careful with the Object Type Casting option. The TS compiler will know that the object is of type `MyClass` but the JavaScript will not: `myClassInstance instanceof MyClass` will return false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript and field initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142071/typescript-and-field-initializers)

Answer (score 9):

If you like the "type casting" method but want to get an actual instance of the class, you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or a helper function like the following:

```
function init<T>(ctor: new () => T, props: Partial<T>): T {
  return Object.assign(new ctor(), props);
}
```

And you can use it like so:

```
class MyClass {
  public numProperty: number = 0;
  public strProperty: string = "";
  public worksWithMethodsToo() {
     console.log("numProperty: "+this.numProperty);
     console.log("strProperty: "+this.strProperty);
  }
}

let myClassInstance = init(MyClass, { numProperty: 100, strProperty: 'hello' });
myClassInstance.worksWithMethodsToo(); // works
```

---

There's also a version of the "constructor initialization" method that allows the constructor to be written more easily by using access modifiers like `public` or `private` on the parameters in the constructor signature to create what's called [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties):

```
class MyClass {
  // body of constructor is not necessary
  constructor(public numProperty: number, public strProperty: string) {}
}

let myClassInstance = new MyClass(100, 'hello');
```

That's more or less the same as your original `MyClass` (parameter names are different I guess), but it cuts down on the boilerplate code.

---

Does that help?  Good luck.

Comment: I like this solution. It is better than creating an empty instance and then assigning all the values step by step.