# How to convert Query Snapshot from Firebase into a different object?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

In the below method, I am retrieving a document from a Firebase collection.

I have managed to log the values I need to return when `getUserByUserId()` is called, but I need to return them as a `User` object:

```
getUserByUserId(userId: string) {
    return of(firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("userId", "==", userId)
      .get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log("User ID", "=>", doc.data().userId);
          console.log("Username", "=>", doc.data().userName);
          console.log("Mechanic", "=>", doc.data().isMechanic);
          console.log("Location", "=>", doc.data().location);
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      }));
  }
```

Here is the `User` structure that the data will need to follow:

```
import { PlaceLocation } from './location.model';

export class User {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public name: string,
        public isMechanic: boolean,
        public email: string,
        public location: PlaceLocation
    ) { }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how I can create a `User` object with this data & return it as the response of `getUserByUserId()`?

Comment: What are you doing inside piped `map()`? map is for manipulating the returned Observable and must return a value. For logging purposes, you can use `tap` Or else, return the object you receive in map

Comment: What I want to use `getUserByUserId()` for is to return the entire `User` object from firebase so that I can assign it to `this.user`

Comment: Just get rid of the map() and try

Comment: Hi @AshishRanjan I've updated my question above, can you please take a look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with [@angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) you can do as follow

```
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
}

getUserByUserId(userId: string) {

    return this.firestore
      .collection("users", ref => ref.where("userId", "==", userId))
      .get()
      .pipe(
        filter(ref => !ref.empty),
        map(ref => ref.docs[0].data() as User),
        map(data => new User(data, data.location))
      )

}
```

updated

if you need object instance you should have additional constructor like this
[about object assign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37682352/943792)

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public name: string,
        public contactNumber: number,
        public isMechanic: boolean,
        public email: string,
        public password: string,
        public address: string,
        public imageUrl: string,
        public location: PlaceLocation
    ) { }

    public constructor(
      init?: Partial<User>,
      initLocation?: Partial<PlaceLocation>) {

        Object.assign(this, init);
        if(initLocation) {
          this.location = new PlaceLocation(initLocation);
        }
    }
}

export class PlaceLocation {
    constructor() { }

    public constructor(init?: Partial<PlaceLocation>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

because you read data as object without type you can only create a new User object explicitly and assign it properties using data from object

```
getUserByUserId(userId: string) {

    return this.firestore
      .collection("users", ref => ref.where("userId", "==", userId))
      .get()
      .pipe(
        filter(ref => !ref.empty),
        map(ref => ref.docs[0].data() as User),
        map(data => new User(data, data.location))
      )

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question with some more code. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that would show me how to `map` the result of `getUserByUserId` to my object, is that possible?

Comment: @user9847788 the last map in function getUserByUserId do mapping - map(data => new User(data, data.location))